# Can the mobile App share only selected attributes to Crashlytics?

Tags: crashlytics, fabric.io, fabric-answers

As part of the crash report, I see several attributes about the mobile, platform, app, crash are gathered by the Crashlytics SDK and sent to Crashlytics.

Due to security concerns, we DO NOT want to send certain attributes (e.g. device rooted status) to Crashlytics. Is there a configuration or way to implement this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. I haven't heard of this particular security concern before. There is not a way to customize the data payload sent over.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response. Our enterprise security team wanted to restrict certain attributes (from Customer mobile) being sent to Crashlytics. Is there plan for such a feature in future releases ?

Comment: Anytime. There are no plans to change this. It's the first request I personally recall for adding this in.